# knitr fail compiling chunk with scan(dec=",")

Tags: r, knitr

What I'm trying is import (copy&paste) some data from Excel with comma as decimal points by using scan(dec=",") command, but I have a problem with knitr when compiling this chunk:

```
<<>>=
conc<-scan(dec=",")
9,562445749
37,66119516
72,9103195

@
```

I get this error: Line 22: Unexpected ','

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

In this case `scan()` requires your to run it in an *interactive* fashion (e.g. it waits for a blank line to terminate input), whereas `knitr`/`Sweave` runs R code in a non-interactive fashion. In general you should avoid code that requires interaction; in other words, you should guarantee the code can be executed without human interaction. For example, this runs on itself regardless of the environment:

```
conc <- scan(dec=",", text='9,562445749
37,66119516
72,9103195
')
```

It is especially important to avoid code which involves with human intervention for the sake of reproducible research, because intervention means the results can not be determined by code itself (depending on human input for each run).

Comment: Thank you @Yihui for your advice, I solved it by using `textConnection`command (very similar to your example)

Comment: @user1489137 that is unnecessary, because `scan()` will set up the `textConnection()` internally when you use the `text` argument; if you do it by yourself, you have to remember to `close()` the connection after you have finished reading the text. So `scan(text=...)` is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space between your last line and the `@`.  This is a problem with Sweave, so perhaps it's a problem with knitr too.  Since scan normally stops when you enter a blank line (and you don't want a blank line), you'll need to enter the number of items you want to scan.

```
<<>>=
conc<-scan(dec=",", n=3)
9,562445749
37,66119516
72,9103195
@
```